# Как сделать редирект yii на прошлую страницу?

Tags: yii2, http, yii, редирект

Есть страница comp/computer?id=15
на ней есть типо отзывы которые можно редактировать comp/computer/update?id=2
Я хочу чтобы после того как изменил отзыв. = вернуться опять к этой странице с товаром.
Если прям в лоб написать таким способом то вернусь, именно к 15.

```
return $this->redirect(["?id=15"]);
```

Но мне кажется нужно как-то отсюда id получить $computers = addComputer::findOne($id); = но если использовать её в actionUpdate = то Unused local variable 'computers'. The value of the variable is not used anywhere.

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
$model = new ReviewForm();
$comment = Review::findOne($id);
$computers = addComputer::findOne($id);  
if ($model->load($this->request->post())) {

  $comment->text = $model->text;
  if ($comment->save(false)) {
    return $this->redirect(["?id=15"]);
  }
  Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
    'success',
    'Success'
  );
}
$model->setAttributes($comment->getAttributes(['name', 'email', 'text']));
return $this->render('update', compact('model'));
```

}

Comment: Возможно вам поможет referer https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было изменить

```
<?= Html::a('Редактировать', Url::to(['computer/update', 'id' => $comment->id])) ?>
```

на

```
<?= Html::a('Редактировать', Url::to(['computer/update', 'id' => $comment->id, 'cid'=>$computers['id'] ])) ?>
```

и поправить actionUpdate
вернув `return $this->redirect(["computer/", "id"=> $cid]);`

```
public function actionUpdate($id,$cid)
  {
    $model = new ReviewForm();
    $comment = Review::findOne($id);

    if ($model->load($this->request->post())) {

      $comment->text = $model->text;
      if ($comment->save(false)) {

        return $this->redirect(["computer/", "id"=> $cid]);
      }

      Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
        'success',
        'Success'
      );
    }

    $model->setAttributes($comment->getAttributes(['name', 'email', 'text']));
    return $this->render('update', compact('model'));
  }
```